# IN asp.net MVC project, accessing HTML page in subdirectory returns 404 error

Tags: html, visual-studio, http-status-code-404

I have a  working project that is built in visual studio as MVC project with angular js. I want to convert it to basic html+angular website. So I created an empty website project, renamed and converted all my cshtml pages to html pages. 
When I run project, home page loads, properly, all the partial pages in root directory ( views ) loads fine. The problem is with pages in subdirectories (views/home). For those pages it gives 404 error. 
I have kept exact same structure as my original MVC website where all pages load properly.
Just for troubleshooting I added another page in subdirectory and set it as startup page. But I get 404 error even if I Run the project or do view in browser.if I copy that page in root directory, it works. 
Does any one faced same issue? Or I need to same more things in an empty project?

Comment: Mvc includes a web.config that prevents linking to view files. Remove it; in \view

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks for the answer, I have tried creating empty website project and putting my files in that. But that also behaved same . I will try your suggestion and get back to you,

Comment: If that's not the issue, then there's something wrong with your links.

Comment: @AndrewBarber- you were right, as i was copying the files from original MVC website, I also moved web.config. that web config was a BlockViewHandler which was blocking the partial views.

Comment: Cool. Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a web.config file in /view which is partially used to prevent view files from being requested directly, since that's not desirable in MVC.

You'll need to find that file, and remove the DenyHandler entry in it to be able to serve links to those directly.

Comment: Dont know why this answer is downvoted. It worked for me.